# Grails change database column size of a hasMany of Strings

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class that looks like the following:

```
class Foo {
    static hasMany = [bar: String]
}
```

The problem is that this creates a join table with a column of `VARCHAR(255)` in MySQL, which much larger than I need it to be.  In my example, bar is a Set not an indexed collection, so trying to use [indexColumn](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Database%20Mapping/indexColumn.html) does not work.  [joinTable](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html) does not have an attribute to change the column type/length.  Is it possible to change to column size without changing the structure of the domain class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works (tested with grails 2.4):

```
class Foo {
    static hasMany = [
        bars:String
    ]

    static mapping = {
        bars joinTable: [column: 'BARS_STRING', length: 112]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `sqlType`, like

```
class Foo {
    static hasMany = [bar: String]

    static mapping = {
        names joinTable: [column: 'bar', sqlType: 'varchar(32)']
    }

}
```